# Python serial read byte

Tags: python, pyserial

I have an interface which has button for the read serial line.

```
    class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self,parent = None):
            QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
            ########################################################################
            # APPLY JSON STYLESHEET
            ########################################################################
            # self = QMainWindow class
            # self.ui = Ui_MainWindow / user interface class
            loadJsonStyle(self, self.ui)
            ########################################################################
            QSizeGrip(self.ui.size_grip)

            self.connection = SerialConnection()
            self.Rs232 = RS232_Data()
self.ui.propertyListBtn.clicked.connect(self.get_property_list)
            self.show()
     def get_property_list(self):
    
                   self.Rs232.read(46,0,self.propertyDataArray) #Read Request

            self.getAllByte = self.connection.serial_read_byte(236)
            print(list(self.getAllByte))
    
           # self.connection.connection_close()
            #self.connection.connection_start()
```

This is the SerialConnection class:

```
import time

import serial

# serialPort = serial.Serial(port = "COM4", baudrate=115200,
#                            bytesize=8, timeout=2, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)


import serial.tools.list_ports
class SerialConnection():
    def __init__(self):
        portList = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
        for p in portList:
            if p.pid == 12345:
                print("Confirmed")
                self.getPortName = p.device
                print(self.getPortName)
                self.serialPort = serial.Serial(port=self.getPortName, baudrate=230400, bytesize=8, timeout=5,
                                                stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
                break
            else:
                ## Show dialog
                print("There is no  device on the line")
    def connection_start(self):
        try:
            self.serialPort.open()
        except Exception:
            print("Port is already open")
    def connection_close(self):
        self.serialPort.close()
    def serial_write(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.serialPort.write(self.data)
    def serial_read_string(self):
        readData = self.serialPort.readline()
        return readData
    def serial_read_byte(self,size):

        readData = self.serialPort.read(size)
        return readData
```

RS232 Class:

```
class RS232_Data():
    def __init__(self):
        self.startOfTheFrame = "0x2621"
        self.endOfTheFrame = "0x0D0A"


        self.startOfTheFrameL = 0x26
        self.startOfTheFrameH = 0x21

        self.endOfTheFrameL = 0x0D
        self.endOfTheFrameH = 0x0A
        self.connection = SerialConnection()


    def read(self,length,type,propertyData = []):
        self.datagram = []
        self.datagram.extend([startOfTheFrameL,startOfTheFrameH])
        self.connection.serial_write(self.dataGram)
```

When I press the button only one time. I get correct value. But If I press second-three-third.. time I get wrong values.
But if I add below lines:

```
   self.connection.connection_close()
   self.connection.connection_start()
```

end of the get_property_list function, I get correct value everytime.
Is there any other way to do this? Do I have to close and open the connection every time?

Comment: What's at the other end of the serial connection? How do you define what's "correct" and what do you receive when you get something which is "incorrect"? What makes sense and what to expect probably also depends on the device and/or its protocol.

Comment: The GUI stuff is probably unnecessary; please review the guidance for creating a [mre]

Comment: I say correct value according to sending from otherside. My correct data start with like this : [35, 32, 119, 104, 235, 0,...] but wrong data could be meanless like this: [51, 45, 12, 14, 2, 5,...] . I didnt share gui function, I want to show serial connection where initilize.

Comment: You can `open()` the serial connection when you initialise the object that needs the connection, then `close()` it when you quit your program. You shouldn't need to `open()` and `close()` every time you fetch or send data. For example, you can call `connection_start()` at the end of your `SerialConnection.__init__()`, then call `connection_close()` in `SerialConnection.__del__()` call.

Comment: You might even prefer calls such as `self.connection.connection_start()` in `MainWindow.__init__()` and `self.connection.connection_close()` in `MainWindow.__del__()` as that will make it clearer that the lifetime of your connection starts and ends with the MainWindow object.

Comment: I tried both of them it didnt work, every time value changing.